# Cocoa - changing the value of an XML node

Tags: objective-c, xml, cocoa

If I have a XML file, whose value I want to change, as shown below:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<items>
<item>
<object>First Object</object>
<description>Description One</description>
</item>
<item>
<object>Second Object</object>
<description>Description Two</description>
</item>
</items>
```

Are there any methods to change say, "Description Two" to "Description Two Modified"? Or do I have somehow, reload all the data again, change the value needed and then saving to file again?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently, the solution to the question is quite simple, and by changing an NSXMLElement using any of the above as an element, the whole document will auto change..

Comment: Would you mind sharing how you did this? I'm having a headache trying to do this